# CKAN - Upload a dataset with tags using API

Tags: api, ckan

I am trying to upload a dataset into CKAN using API. All works well is I don't set the tags.

I have tried as an array:

```
'tags': [u'dairy', u'gender', u'policy', u'value chain', u'value systems'],
```

Also as a comma separated list:

```
'tags': u'dairy,gender,policy,value chain,value systems',
```

But in both cases I get this error:

> Format incorrect: Only lists of dicts can be placed against subschema
>   ('tags',), not

How should I upload the tags for a dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
tags=[{'name': 'tag1'}, {'name': 'tag2'}]
```

If you're using the ckanapi python library, this would look like:

```
import ckanapi
ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN(url, apikey=...)
ckan.action.package_create(name='test', tags=[{'name': 'tag1'}, {'name': 'tag2'}])
```